# Simplify $N\setminus \{7\} \cup \{ n\in N: n \geq 7\}$. Is my answer right? (simple, quick, trivial)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$N\setminus \{7\} \cup \{ n\in N: n \geq 7\} = N$

Can you approve my answer? I just want to be sure I am right.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: If by u you mean union you are right

Answer (score 1):

This looks correct. You take the set of natural numbers, you take away the element $7$. Then, you combine that with the set of natural numbers which are equal to or greater than $7$—this includes $7$.

Comment: Thank you Sir, that's what I thought. I will accept your answer in couple minutes when I'm allowed to.